# Power Commands for Visual Studio 2017 doesn't format XAML?

Tags: xaml, format, visual-studio-2017, powercommands

I couldn't find any documentation on this but I use Power Commands for Visual Studio with the Power Commands to format my document when I save. And I really love this tool. But for some reason it won't format XAML code. Even though I can format XAML using the known <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> command.

I thought it would just format anything that would be formatted when using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, but apparently it doesn't? How can I fix this? Is there another workaround so I can **save AND format XAML with one command**?

Comment: The formatting capability refers to the editor you're using to each file extension. The `XAML` was commonly edited as an `XML` and the formatting is a bit different, indeed. Just update to the new `visual studio` and `xamarin` versions. It's already supporting it like a charm.